# Why force_unicode used?

Tags: python, django

I have inherited code which has a method to convert a django model to dictionary . Now, I don't understand why force_unicode is used here?

```
def model_to_dictonary(instance):
    for field in instance._meta.fields:
       if isinstance(field, ForeignKey):
          dictionay_obj[field.name] = force_unicode(getattr(instance, field.name))
```

In fact this line (force_unicode) throws an excpetion if the object(ie foreignkey) is null.

thanks

Comment: `force_unicode` is a custom method in your code. It could do anything. But my guess is that it's basically `lambda x: unicode(x)`. If it fails because the field is set to `None` (I'm assuming that's what you mean by `null`) on the specific instance, you must correct that instance or the foreign key specification.

Comment: Are you using Django force_unicode function? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#useful-utility-functions

Answer (score 2):

If it is the force_unicode() from django, then it needs a string to (wait for it) force to be represented using unicode: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/

(If so, you should add "django" as a tag.)

Comment: Yeh true. Now I get it. We are doing force_unicode since we want to save the value as string